# Create Report via REST/SOAP API

Tags: rest-api, api, reporting, soap-api, reports-api

I need to create simple `Report` with `Lead`/`Contact` data. How can I do it via REST/SOAP API? REST is preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Ask and you shall receive. See [Introducing the Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm), and more specifically [Get Report Data without Saving Changes to or Creating a Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_report_query_example.htm) (emphasis mine):

> ## Get Report Data without Saving Changes to or Creating a Report
>
> **Run a report without creating a report or changing an existing one by making a POST request to the query resource.** Get report data without filling up your org with unnecessary reports.
>
> ### Example
>
> Get report data using the query resource.
>
> ```
> /services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/query
> ```
>
> Include report criteria as reportMetadata in the POST request body. This POST request gets data about Opportunities:
>
> ```json
>     {
>     "reportMetadata" : {
>         "aggregates" : [ "RowCount" ],
>         "chart" : null,
>         "crossFilters" : [ ],
>         "currency" : null,
>         "description" : null,
>         "detailColumns" : [ "OPPORTUNITY_NAME", "TYPE", "LEAD_SOURCE", "AMOUNT", "CLOSE_DATE", "NEXT_STEP", "STAGE_NAME", "PROBABILITY", "FISCAL_QUARTER", "AGE", "CREATED_DATE", "FULL_NAME", "ROLLUP_DESCRIPTION", "ACCOUNT_NAME" ],
>         "developerName" : "OpportunityReport",
>         "division" : null,
>         "folderId" : "00DD000000086ujMAA",
>         "groupingsAcross" : [ ],
>         "groupingsDown" : [ ],
>         "hasDetailRows" : true,
>         "hasRecordCount" : true,
>         "historicalSnapshotDates" : [ ],
>         "id" : "00OD0000001leVCMAY",
>         "name" : "Matrix",
>         "reportBooleanFilter" : null,
>         "reportFilters" : [ ],
>         "reportFormat" : "MATRIX",
>         "reportType" : {
>           "label" : "Opportunities",
>           "type" : "Opportunity"
>         },
>         "scope" : "organization",
>         "showGrandTotal" : true,
>         "showSubtotals" : true,
>         "sortBy" : [ ],
>         "standardDateFilter" : {
>           "column" : "CLOSE_DATE",
>           "durationValue" : "CUSTOM",
>           "endDate" : null,
>           "startDate" : null
>         },
>         "standardFilters" : [ {
>           "name" : "open",
>           "value" : "all"
>         }, {
>           "name" : "probability",
>           "value" : ">0"
>         } ]
>       }
>     }
> ```

---

The [Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_list_resource.htm) section of the documentation (specifically the `PATCH Request Body` section) goes into great detail about how to structure the JSON. It looks like the same structure.

Also, another useful endpoint listed in the [Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm) section of the documentation can help you inspect existing reports you want to mimic if you're stuck.

> ```
>  /services/data/<latest API version>/analytics/reports/<report ID>/describe
> ```

---

Here is a basic example I got working for `Lead` data. Set the `folderId` to your own `Organization Id`.

```json
    {
        "reportMetadata": {
            "aggregates": ["RowCount"],
            "chart": null,
            "crossFilters": [],
            "currency": null,
            "description": null,
            "detailColumns": ["OWNER", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "TITLE", "COMPANY", "LEAD_SOURCE", "RATING", "STREET", "EMAIL"],
            "developerName": "LeadReport",
            "division": null,
            "folderId": "00D290000000SuCEAU",
            "groupingsAcross": [],
            "groupingsDown": [],
            "hasDetailRows": true,
            "hasRecordCount": true,
            "historicalSnapshotDates": [],
            "id": "",
            "name": "Matrix",
            "reportBooleanFilter": null,
            "reportFilters": [],
            "reportFormat": "MATRIX",
            "reportType": {
                "label": "Leads",
                "type": "LeadList"
            },
            "scope": "user",
            "showGrandTotal": true,
            "showSubtotals": true,
            "sortBy": [],
            "standardDateFilter": {
                "column": "CREATED_DATE",
                "durationValue": "CUSTOM",
                "endDate": null,
                "startDate": null
            },
            "standardFilters": []
        }
    }
```